# Jquery code not working when it's use as link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I wrote a some jquery code and  when i use that in  tags, it works.

```
<script>...jquery codes...</script>
```

But if i copy/paste to js file and use as link like:

```
<script src="Scripts/getAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's not working.
Why?
And how can i fix this?
Thanx

Comment: Could you check whether the js file is getting loaded into the page or not?

Comment: post the code, could be something in there.

Comment: can u show your js code?

Comment: Could we see the code? Are you including that <script> tag before jquery? Are you waiting for the dom to be ready?

Comment: To get the obvious out of the way. Does the value in the src attribute actually work?

Comment: Any error message ? Are you sure your js file is at the right place ?...

Comment: It solved. I replaced

var ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim = $('#<%= ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
with this

var ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim = $('#ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim').get(0).selectedIndex;
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved. I replaced

```
var ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim = $('#<%= ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex;
```

with this

```
var ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim = $('#ddlSorguTalepEdenBirim').get(0).selectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, are you sure that "Scripts/getAjax.js" should not be "/Scripts/getAjax.js" (or "~/Scripts/getAjax.js" in case you are using asp.net).